# How to disable Pycharm cache?

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I made a program that takes up to 20 seconds to start when executed manually (outside Pycharm). This is probably because of a disatrous import policy plus non-optimization. But I did not realize how bad it was until I started to deploy it, because when I execute it from Pycharm, the first execution of the session takes some time indeed, but then the next executions are very fast (2sec). I assume Pycharm keeps some packages in cache or something like that. How could I disable that in order to troubleshoot my application loading time in "real conditions"?

Comment: Run your application outside PyCharm. (as you should do with final product). It is also impoortant to see other problems

Comment: Yes, but I want to use Pycharm debugging and profiling tools. This is a big app, it will be very hard to optimize without IDE tracing tools.

Comment: But for that, it is fully normal you have a lot of extra loading time.

Comment: That a cache of Pycharm is causing the change is no more than a hypothesis I guess. Do you have any evidence of that?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is not clear. What I mean is that when running the application normally, it takes 20sec to start. In Pycharm, where I would like to monitor this loading time, it takes 20sec as well, but only the first time I execute my program. After that, the next executions from Pycharm (even if I close and re-open it), takes a "normal" 2sec, which make it hard for me to identify what took so long the first time.

Comment: @Munshine loading in the OS the first time caches are also being initialized, the next executions should be faster if you don't kill the terminal. Otherwise you can clear caches in PyCharm before each execution, the IDE itself should have more overhead than running directly in the terminal, since you're loading the debugger and profiling tools etc. (PyCharm cache is saved to file, thus persistent. If you run outside the IDE in the terminal cache is transient and gets wiped every time you kill the process.)